# Trig identity $\frac{\cos x}{\sec x} + \frac{\sin x}{\csc x} = \csc^2x - \cot^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a simple trig identity problem that I can't seem to figure out. I keep going off course in identifying the answer. Here's the problem:

$$
\frac {\cos x}{\sec x} + \frac {\sin x}{\csc x}
$$

The answer is:

$$
\csc^2x-\cot^2x
$$

I just don't see how they got that answer. I got different solutions, but never that one.

Comment: What are you going from? Because the first expression equates to $1$ the second is obtained by $$\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2x$$ divide through by $\tan^2 x$ but this still doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{\cos x}{\sec x}+\frac{\sin x}{\csc x}=\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x=1$$

and

$$\csc^2 x-\cot^2 x=\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}-\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\sin^2 x}=1$$

Comment: You may want to include some sort of argument for your trig functions.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is not properly written :) Edited.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\frac{\cos(x)}{\sec(x)}+\frac{\sin(x)}{\csc(x)}=\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2$$

Comment: why did i got $-1$ i don't understand

Comment: I did not downvote you, but you have a $\csc$ instead of $\cos$ in your answer.

Comment: thank you it was a typo, sorry

Answer (score 1):

We know that $csc(x)=\frac{1}{sin(x)}$ and similarly $sec(x) = \frac{1}{cos(x)}$.  Therefore,

$$
\frac{cos(x)}{sec(x)}=\frac{cos(x)}{1/cos(x)}=cos^2(x)
$$

Doing the same thing for your other term you get $cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)=1$, which is a basic trig identity.  Another basic trig identity is that $csc^2(x)-cot^2(x)=1$.  Your problem and your solution both equal 1 and are therefore equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

$$p=\frac{\cos x}{\sec x}+\frac{\sin x}{\csc x}$$
$$p=\frac{\cos x}{\frac1{\cos x}}+\frac{\sin x}{\frac1{\sin x}}$$
Using the algebraic identity $$\frac{a}{(\frac bc)}=\frac{ac}{b}$$
We have 
$$p=\cos^2x+\sin^2x$$
$$p=1$$
Then we focus on 
$$q=\csc^2x-\cot^2x$$
$$q=\frac1{\sin^2x}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}$$
$$q=\frac{1-\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}$$
The Pythagorean identity $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$ gives
$$q=\frac{\sin^2x}{\sin^2x}$$
$$q=1$$
$$p=q$$
QED